# JavaScript — Randomly assign 8 unique numbers to each class name

Tags: javascript, random, menu

I need to randomly assign 6 unique numbers (0-5) to 6 class names. One number to each of the class names

How this is being used: 
When the hamburger icon is clicked, the menu opens and displays 6 rows of individual's names with background images specific to each one. The "transition" is for the profiles to stair-step in.

Here is what I have so far, but I am getting repeated numbers. I want the numbers to be assigned randomly, so the profiles are in a different order each time the menu is opened.

```
var generate_random_number = function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    return number;
};

var build_menu_profiles = function() {
    $(".profile-0").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 1</div>");
    $(".profile-1").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 2</div>");
    $(".profile-2").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 3</div>");
    $(".profile-3").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 4</div>");
    $(".profile-4").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 5</div>");
    $(".profile-5").html("<div class='profile-title'><span class='emphasis'>Profile</span> 6</div>");
};

var animate_menu_profiles = function(i) {
    i = 0; 

    $(".profiles").each(function(i) {
        $(this).toggleClass("transition-" + i);
        $(this).toggleClass("profile-" + generate_random_number());

        build_menu_profiles();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to generate random numbers so much as you want to shuffle a known set of six numbers. Here's one way to do that:

```
var indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5].sort(function(a,b) { return Math.random()-0.5; });
  // produces [3,1,5,4,0,2] or whatever
```

Then you can use that in your loop as follows:

```
$(".profiles").each(function(i) {
    $(this).toggleClass("transition-" + i);
    $(this).toggleClass("profile-" + indices[i]);
    ...
```

Note that using `.sort()` and `Math.random()` together like that is kind of a hack, but for your purposes it should work well enough.

**But**, your existing `.each()` loop isn't going to do the job. Currently when it processes each element it uses `.toggle()`, which means if the element already has the `profile-x` class name it will be removed, otherwise it will be added. Put that together with the randomisation and some elements will end up with no `profile-x` class, and some will end up with more than one.

In my opinion, the easiest thing is to actually move the elements around rather than changing their classes. I'll assume they have a common parent with `class="profile-container"`:

```
var animate_menu_profiles = function(i) {
    var $profileContainer = $(".profile-container");
    var $profiles = $(".profiles");
    $profiles.sort(function(a,b) { return Math.random()-0.5; });
    $profiles.each(function(i){
        $(this)
          .toggleClass("transition-" + i)
          .appendTo($profileContainer);
    });

    build_menu_profiles();
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/okz4y1jL/2/

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense and really helped with seeing a better approach. It works. I had to move the transition into its own function so the animation works. It builds the profile and shuffles them when the page loads, then when the menu is opened, the profiles are already there to animate.

Answer (score 1):

I like nnnnnn's answer better but to your question:

The issue here is that you get repeated numbers, so check to see if you have already returned that number before returning it:

https://jsbin.com/watuvi/1/edit?js,console

```
var numbers = [];
var generate_random_number = function() {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  if (numbers.indexOf(number) === -1) {
    numbers.push(number);
  } else {
    return generate_random_number();
  }
};

generate_random_number();
generate_random_number();
generate_random_number();
generate_random_number();
generate_random_number();
generate_random_number();

console.log(numbers);
```